# Avoiding layout redundancy

Tags: android, android-layout, dry

I would like to have Buttons B1 and B2 at the right of the row and Buttons A1 and A2 centered in the remaining space in that row.

[image: Centering within remainder]

Is this possible without wrapping Buttons A **twice**?

**Here are the details to make the question concrete.**

Eclipse critiques the two parent layouts to `@id/buttonAx` by saying that "This LinearLayout layout or RelativeLayout parent is possibly useless".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myRightMostLL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonB1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonB2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/myRightMostLL">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/remainderLL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonA1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonA2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A2" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And yet I needed this uselessness to be able to center Buttons A in the space remaining after Buttons B has been laid out. Can one obtain the same effect with just one parent wrapper layout for Buttons A?

In layouts such as this one I am also often questioning whether it is really necessary for @id/myRightMostLL to appear *first* in the file.

Comment: I can't really think of another solution for this besides setting left and right margins for button A but I don't think that would be a versatile method. Honestly if it's producing the desired result I would just suppress that warning because it just doesn't understand what you need.

Comment: Are the additional buttons to be grouped with ButtonA, ButtonB, or some with each? How would they be positioned? It would be better to tell us your actual requirements instead of a vague warning that a two-button-only solution won't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with a single layout, using a couple of "filler" views to take up space:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A2" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A3" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you're targeting API 14 or later, you can use [`Space`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) widgets instead of `View` in the above. `Space` is just a light-weight alternative to a `View`, designed specifically for this kind thing.

Comment: Impressive. So layout_weight simply acts as a sort of spring. There is no need for the views holding that attribute to be either adjacent or to partition (as in add up to the total size of) the parent.

Comment: @Calaf - Nope. Just let the blank views eat up all the extra space.

Answer (score 1):

Solution below doesn't show possibly useless warning :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
                    android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
                    android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

http://clip2net.com/s/5nna7M

Comment: That's exactly the answer I meant to avoid (because I don't know how to extend it to the four-button case). But maybe you do. Can you look at the (now extended) question and see if your answer can be adapted to it?

Comment: But I would like two buttons to be flush right ("right justified") and the other two to be centered in the remaining space.

Comment: Your answer contains valuable hints. You've also answered my secondary question (last sentence in my post). Contrary to what I had gathered (that Android uses a one-pass XML parser), it is in fact not necessary to write 'android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layRight"' *after* "layRight" has been defined.

Comment: I would be so sure of that. By positioning layout  to the left of other one - you can be sure that it will use space left. If you omit totheleftof attribute - it will center but taking up all width (and not available).

Comment: There is something I don't understand. You write android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layRight" *with* a plus sign. That makes sense, since you are introducing layRight at this point, the plus sign is necessary. But doesn't that mean that when you write a few lines later android:id="@+id/layRight" the plus sign should be omitted (because layRight has been introduced), even if the actual layout is only then being assigned?

Comment: Okay I misunderstood your comment. You are right - I used extra + sign (simply a typo) which doesn't affect performance - it won't create second entry in R.java